# How to retrieve row count of one-to-many relation while also including original entity?

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, projection, criteria-api

Say I have two entities `Foo` and `Bar` where `Foo` has-many `Bar`'s,

```
class Foo {
  int ImportantNumber { get; set; }
  IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

class FooDTO {
  Foo Foo { get; set; }
  int BarCount { get; set; }
}
```

How can I efficiently sum up the number of `Bars` per `Foo` in a DTO using a single query, preferrably only with the Criteria interface.

I have tried any number of ways to get the original entity out of a query with ´SetProjection´ but no luck. The current theory is to do something like

```
SELECT 
  Foo.*, BarCounts.counts 
FROM
  Foo LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT fooId, COUNT(*) as counts FROM Bar GROUP BY fooId ) AS BarCounts 
    ON Foo.id=BarCounts.fooId
```

but with Criterias, and I just can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criteria is probably not the best API for this... HQL is easier:

```
var fooDTOs = session.CreateQuery(@"
              select foo as Foo,
                     count(elements(foo.Bars)) as BarCount
              from Foo foo
              group by foo.id, foo.ImportantNumber
              ")
              .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<FooDTO>())
              .List<FooDTO>();
```

Comment: Thanks, that certainly works and helps. I'm still holding out for a criteria based solution since I would later like to `CriteriaTransformer.TransformToRowCount` that summary to do pagination on it in a single unit. If nothing comes along in a couple of days I'll certainly award you the "accepted answer", until then I'll give you an up vote at least.